# MySQL не записывает большой текст

Tags: mysql

Текст (10 000+ символов) при записи в БД обрезается, записывается не весь.
Текст меньшего размера записывается полностью.

Текст приходит в php файл через POST, затем записывается в БД.
 `POST_MAX_SIZE=256M`, в MySQL тип стоит `TEXT`.

В чем может быть проблема? :(

Comment: Если размер задаваемого в столбце BLOB или TEXT значения превосходит максимально допустимую длину столбца, то это значение соответствующим образом усекается.

Comment: Будьте добры показать структуру таблицы в которую вы вставляете

Comment: Apelsin2020, тогда какой тип я могу использовать под такой текст?
MoloF, вот - https://i.imgur.com/TPXNh4E.png

Comment: LONGTEXT вполне подойдёт

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Существует 4 типа `TEXT`, каждый из которых может помещать в себя разное кол-во данных.
Если идти с меньшего к большему, то получается вот так:

`TINYTEXT, TEXT, MEDIUMTEXT, LONGTEXT`

**Они могут вмещать в себя:**

`TINYTEXT`: 256 байт.

`TEXT`: 65 535 байт.

`MEDIUMTEXT`: 16 777 215 байт.

`LONGTEXT`: 4 294 967 295 байт.

**Переводя последние два получится так:**

`MEDIUMTEXT` - 16 МБ

`LONGTEXT` - 4 ГБ

Для 10 000 символов вполне хватит `MEDIUMTEXT`